# Search an Array Android

Tags: android, arrays, search

I have a textbox and search button, now all I need is the code to implement searching an array. The array I have is called Facts_Array (consists of strings). Comment if you need any more information.

Comment: How far is your understanding of Java? Searching an array is elementary, I would suggest you first attempt, then when you reach a roadblock we can help.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I simply had an error when I tried some of my own code. I had forgot to implement findViewById. For some reason Eclipse was telling me something not directly related to it.... Kind of hard to explain, I figured it out though.

Comment: Sorry.... I just needed to find out what my error derived from. Compare codes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
EditText searchField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchfield);
Button searchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchbutton);
searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        for (String s : Facts_Array) {
            if (searchField.getText().toString().contains(s)) {
                // Do stuff
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Of course, you might want to refine the actual search bit some more (right now it's just using `contains()`), at least by ignoring case.

Comment: Thanks, I had basically this same thing, just missing findViewById... Can't believe I had forgot to implement this.

Comment: Looping linearly over the entire array is one way to do this, the slowest possible way, but it's a way. If you have a large array, you might want to check the Arrays class and look at the search methods there (much faster, more efficient). Also, if you don't want to "do stuff" multiple times, or keep searching the array after you find a match, make sure you break the loop.

Comment: I would indeed use a different method of searching the array, especially if it's large. I was just trying to demonstrate an elementary way of doing it. As Charlie suggested, you should take a look at the Java API perhaps for a more efficient method.

Answer (score 0):

But, I do not think I understood exactly if I can use it just for the
search i need.
e.g.: to retrieve the typed text and return my search response,
provided from a web service.

So, basically i need just the design, not it's functionality.

Can someone tell me if i can use this bar only for my personal data,
not a general search from internet or the hole phone,
and i would appreciate link for a simple and clear tutorial, because i
couldn't found anything concrete till now.